# Unable to connect to remote mySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-12.04

I've been trying the following code to attempt to connect to a remote database I'm hosting on digital ocean.

```
    MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection("Server = 104.236.197.146; Port = 3306; Database = BattleRoyale; Uid = root; Pwd = password");
    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show( e.ToString(), "Database connection error" , MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
```

Whenever I attemt to run this code I get the following error:

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySql hosts.

I believe the problem is with the hosted database. I've tried the following things:

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@"%" IDENTIFIED BY 'rootPass';

I've been trying to check to see if TCP/IP is enabled, but I cannot find it via phpMyAdmin nor going through putty or anything.

As you can tell, I don't know much about Linux machines and I'm just trying to connect to this database to work on a school project. Who knows what I've done trying to fix this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the server reachable from your location? Try to ping it. if ping is successfull, you could also try to use a socket to just build up a tcp/ip connection to the ip/port just to be sure there is someone on the other side listening...

Comment: If you are allowing connections from all hosts '%' it doesn't necessarily mean that it'd allow remove connection. Try doing a telnet 104.236.197.146 3306 and see if you are able to connect. I think the issue is here only. If you are unable to connect, you need to enable the port in Firewall.

Comment: try telnet to the server and port you're using, seeing you can actually establish the connection - to rule out firewalling

Comment: Attempted open 104.236.197.146 3306 and got an error, it just says "Connect failed" any ideas of what to try next?

Comment: @KrishnanduSarkar ... or make sure that MySQL listens on the correct public IP address(es). While it's the firewall in many cases, this has been a problem for me lately.

Comment: @user3376703 See my answer and check bullet point 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible reasons include:

1. MySQL is configured to listen on "localhost" or 127.0.0.1 only - this does not allow remote connections at all, regardless of the firewall configuration
2. Firewall may be configured to not let through communication on port 3306
3. MySQL may not be running on the standard port 3306 but some other port

Most probably it's 1. or 2. Especially 1. is something you don't think of at first.

Please note that many hosters don't allow access to the databases from outside their own network. That's why often PhpMySQL works but remote connections don't.

Comment: What steps would I have to take to fix 1 and 2? Remember, I'm really new with Linux machines.

Comment: For step 1: Open the my.cnf file (not sure where that is in your installation, but you'll find out - maybe in /etc or /etc/mysql) and check the `bind-address` option. See manual for details. For step 2: Ask that question on superuser.com, as this is off-topic for this site.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. Changed the bind-address to 0.0.0.0 and now my C# code can connect. Thanks again!